# Correct SQL Server linked server connection settings to MySQL that will allow inserts

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I'm in linked server hell!  I've created a linked server to a remote MySQL database.  I'm able to query and do updates.  However when I attempt an insert I get an error:

```
"[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.0.92-log]Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".
```

What are the correct Settings I should have?  I realize there are 3 components with settings (MySQL ODBC Driver, MSDASQL Provider, Linked Server Object).  Here's what I have so far:

```
ODBC Driver:
Connection Tab: Nothing checked.
Metadata Tab: Nothing checked.
Cursors/Results Tab:  
     Don't Cache Results of forward-only cursors - checked
     Force use of forward-only cursors - checked
     Return mached rows instead of affected rows - checked
Debug Tab:  Nothing checked.
SSL Tab: Nothing checked.
Misc Tab: Nothing Checked.

MSDASQL Provider:
     The following are checked:
     Nested Queries
     Level zero only
     Allow inprocess

Linked Server:

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @srvproduct=N'MySQL', @provider=N'MSDASQL', @datasrc=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @provstr=N'DSN=HOMEPROJECTADMIN;OPTION=3'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL

GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'collation compatible', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'data access', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'dist', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'pub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'sub', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'connect timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'collation name', @optvalue=null
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'lazy schema validation', @optvalue=N'false'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'query timeout', @optvalue=N'0'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'use remote collation', @optvalue=N'true'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'HOMEPROJECTADMIN', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'true'
GO
```

Comment: you should flag this for migration to dba.se - more likely to get mileage on that site.

Comment: Do you have MS-DTC setup and working on the server correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick observation: you using MySQL 5.1 Driver against MySQl 5.0.92

I recommend you should either

- downgrade to MySQL 5.0 ODBC Driver (easier option)
- upgrade to MySQL 5.1.61

Comment: The MySQL server is a hosted server at GoDaddy.com so I'll have a go at downgrading the ODBC Driver.

Comment: Is there a 64-bit 5.0 ODBC Driver?  I installed the 32-bit version that I found but when I start to add a new DSN I only see the 5.1 driver in the list of drivers available.  Do I need to uninstall the 5.1 driver?  Reboot the server?